# How do I keep track of double array items index with ramda map?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have this array:
`[[x,x,x,x][x,x,x,x][x,x,x,x][x,x,x,x]]`

I want to loop and transform these items and return a new array. So I need to track both array and array item index:

```
const mapIndexed = R.addIndex(R.map)
const columns = mapIndexed((col, cidx) => // I need ridx here)
const nextGrid = mapIndexed((row, ridx) => columns, currentGrid)
```

this doesn't work.

Comment: `arr => mapIndexed((row, ridx) => mapIndexed((col, cidx) => …, row), arr)`?

Comment: you point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off @bergi's suggestion of mapIndexed

```
const matrix = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'],
    ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3'],
    ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4'],
]

const mapIndexed = addIndex(map)

const map2d = (f, l) => 
  mapIndexed((row, x) =>
             mapIndexed((col, y) => f(col, x, y), row), l)

map2d((...x) => x, matrix)
// => [[["a1", 0, 0], ["b1", 0, 1], ["c1", 0, 2] etc...
```